# ¿Cómo puedo ir cambiando los header en HTML, dependiendo de en qué página se encuentre el usuario?

Tags: php, html, html5

Tengo mi pagina de index.php que incluye código HTML y PHP, que tiene una etiqueta HTML que es  "a" que tiene un texto que es  "Mi cuenta" que se encuentra en el Header y que direcciona al usuario  a un formulario para que ingrese su correo y contraseña, el problema que tengo es que no sé cómo sacar la etiqueta "mi cuenta" cuando el usuario ya se encuentra loggeado.

Esto me genera un conflicto porque tengo una variable de sesión que ocupa el lugar de la etiqueta "Mi cuenta", es por esto que necesito ocultar o sacar la etiqueta mi cuenta.

Pagina principal

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos.css">
    <title>Blizzard</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header class="Encabezado"> 

        <div id="Contenedor">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="Imagenes/Blizzard.png" id="Logo"></a>      
            
            /*** Necesito eliminar esta etiqueta o que no salga cuando el usuario pueda logearse ***/
            <a id="Mi-Cuenta" class="Link , L-Ploma , L-Negrita" href="Login.html">Mi cuenta</a></li>

            <div id="V-Session">
               <?php
                if(empty($_SESSION['Correo'])){
                   
                }else{
                    echo $_SESSION['Correo'];
                }        
               ?> 
            </div>   

        </div>            
    </header>

    <div>
        <p class="L-Blanca , L-Grande">Juegos</p>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <p id="P-Blizzard" class="L-Ploma , L-Normal">Blizzard</p>
    </div>

        
    
    <div ID="ContenedorJuegos">
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/Star2.PNG"></a>
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/Diablo.png"></a>
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/Over.PNG" alt=""></a>
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/Over2.PNG" alt=""></a>
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/World1.PNG" alt=""></a>
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/Hearts.PNG" alt=""></a>
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/Heroes.PNG" alt=""></a>
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/Warcraft.PNG" alt=""></a>
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/Diablo4.PNG" alt=""></a>
        <a class="IMG-Juego" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/Arcade.PNG" alt=""></a>
       
    </div>
   

</body>
</html>
```

Formulario Login

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos.css">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="FormularioLogin" class="Formulario">

     <form action="V-Login.php" method="POST">
        
        <input type="email" id="Correo" name="Correo" placeholder="Correo electrónico" class="I-200-PX" required>
        <input type="password" id="Contraseña" name="Contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" class="I-200-PX" required>

        <input type="submit" id="Ingresar" value="Iniciar sesión" class="BotonCeleste , BTN-215-PX">
    </form>

     <a href="Registro.html" id="Enlace" class="Link , L-Centrado , L-Celeste">Crear cuenta</a>

    </div>
 
    
</body>
</html>
```

Valida Login

```
<?php
session_start();

$Correo=$_POST['Correo'];
$Contraseña=$_POST['Contraseña'];

$nombre_servidor = "127.0.0.1";
$nombre_usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$nombre_bd = "users";


$Conexion = mysqli_connect ($nombre_servidor, $nombre_usuario, $password, $nombre_bd);

if (!$Conexion) {
    die("La conexión falló: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }


/***** Consultar si el usuario existe ****/

$stmt = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios where Correo = ? and Contraseña = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $Correo, $Contraseña);
$stmt->execute();

$resultado = $stmt->get_result();

   
/***** Usuario existe enviar a pagina principal ****/

if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['Correo'] = $Correo;  
    header('location:index.php');

/***** Usuario no existe, mantenerse en Login ****/   
}else{
    echo "<script>
      alert('Credenciales incorrectas');
      window.location = 'Login.html';
    </script>";
}

$stmt->close();
$Conexion->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puedes realizar lo siguiente.

```
<a id="Mi-Cuenta" class="Link , L-Ploma , L-Negrita" href="Login.html"><?php echo isset($_SESSION['admin'])? '' : 'Mi cuenta' ?></a>
```

Utilizando un if ternario, lo que se realiza es, consulto si existe un usuario logueado via session, colocara en vacio el texto, en caso contrario LOGIN

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu idea

Comment: En el texto donde dice mi cuenta solo debes de colocar lo siguiente..

<?php echo isset($_SESSION['Correo'])? '' : 'Mi cuenta' ?>

Comment: Lo revise, pero lo que pasa es que solamente queda oculto, pero igual esta

Comment: En tu texto, comentas que deseas ocultar..

Comment: quiero sacarlo, no ocultarlo, por que cuando paso el mouse me cambia a la manito

Comment: Prueba esto.

<a id="Mi-Cuenta" class="Link , L-Ploma , L-Negrita" href="Login.html" style="display:<?php echo isset($_SESSION['Correo'])? 'none' : 'block' ?>"> Mi cuenta </a>

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió :)